# Compare 2 Table ID and return with a Boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Query for SQL-Server:**

```sql
SELECT table1.id, talbe2.id,
       IIF(talbe2.id IS NULL, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') as bolean
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN talbe2 ON (table1.id = talbe2.id);

SELECT * FROM table1

SELECT * FROM talbe2
```

**Query Output for SQL-Server:**
[image]

**Our query in MySQL is:**

```sql
SELECT table_1.table1_id, table_2.table2_id,
       IF(table_2.table2_id IS NULL, FALSE, TRUE) as bolean
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON (table_1.table1_id = table_2.table2_id);
```

**Table 1 From MySQL:**

[image]

**Table 2 From MySQL:**

[image]

**Output From MySQL:** The output was right and did my friend goal however this is MySQL and I have no background knowledge in SQL Server since Im also just a student. Our goal here is to get this output but on SQL Server implementation. However the SQL-Server query only showing TRUE and now showing the FALSE we also want it to show.

[image]

Comment: Images of code, and data, don't help us help you. Post the code and data as what it *is*, `text`. Code is best "served" in code fences/blocks, Sample data as DDL and DML statements, and expected results as well formatted tabular `text` or in a markdown table.

Comment: You could use IIF in stead of if: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_iif.asp

Comment: I got the SQL- Server now but not showing the false wait let me edit this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query:

```sql
/*Table create*/
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    info VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    info VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
);

/*Data*/
INSERT INTO table1
(info)
VALUES
('test1'),
('test2'),
('test3'),
('test4');

INSERT INTO table2
(info)
VALUES
('test1'),
('test2'),
('test3'),
('test4'),
('test5'),
('test6');

SELECT * FROM table1;

SELECT * FROM table2;

/*View*/
SELECT table1.id, table2.id,
IIF(table2.id IS NULL, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') as bolean
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id);
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can implement using below

example:

```
drop table if exists #temp;

select 1 as table1_id ,'A' as table1_Name 
into #temp union all
select 2,'B' union all
select 3,'A' union all
select 4,'B' union all
select 5,'A' 
 
drop table if exists #temp1;  

select 1 as table2_id ,'A' as table1_Name 
into #temp1   union all
select 2,'B'union all
select 3,'A'union all
select 4,'B'

SELECT table_1.table1_id, table_2.table2_id,
case when  table_2.table2_id IS NULL then 0
else 1 end as [boolean]
FROM #temp table_1
LEFT JOIN #temp1 table_2 ON (table_1.table1_id = table_2.table2_id);

or 


SELECT table_1.table1_id, table_2.table2_id,
iif(table_2.table2_id IS NULL,0,1) as [boolean]
FROM #temp table_1
LEFT JOIN #temp1 table_2 ON (table_1.table1_id = table_2.table2_id);
```

Comment: the only problem now is the FALSE is not showing that's what I did to my query too but i use string

Comment: then i should use  IIF(talbe2.id = table1.id, 'FALSE', 'TRUE') as bolean

Comment: oh i know why it is not showing now because i used ON (table1.id = talbe2.id);

Comment: Don't know how to show the false